# jax-ws-catalog xml in Soap webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

i have java client service for .net 3.0 server.
 
In client service, i have two types of flow
 
1)using remote wsdllocation url, i able to fetch the services list from remote.
 
2)using local wsdl path,i able to fetch the services from local wsdl file and then binding to remote url for response.In that they used jax-ws-catalog xml for mapping local wsdl path for url location

My question is
 
 
1)at what situation used client service using remote wsdllocation url and local wsdl file?
 
 
2)how we generate local wsdl file and jax-ws-catalog xml in META-INF folder? is it manually create or by any commands in tool?
 
i used 'apache-cxf' tool for create class file using command 'wsdl2java -frontend' but it not generate META-INF folder.
 Thanks